# DRY in ASP.NET MVC - details display vs. edit form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC and I hit this problem: I have a "view product details" form that I want to reuse as an add/edit form. (When you look at the product details, if you have the rights to do it an Edit link should appear; it should redisplay the same form, but with the textbox fields enabled this time.)

Right now the Details view looks something like this:

```
<% var product = ViewData.Model; %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= Html.TextBox("Name", product.Name, new { size = "50", disabled = "disabled"})%></td>
  </tr>
```

Is there a way I could reuse it without putting too much logic in the view? For example, I will need to remove the `disabled = "disabled"` part (but the `size` part needs to stay there), to put everything inside a form and so on.

If it can't be done, that's fine, I'm just trying not to repeat the same thing several times in case I need to change it (and I will).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always pass in a value indicating what mode you're in or what privileges you have:

```
ViewData.Model.CanEdit
```

So you might want to create a composite class for your model instead of just using Product

```
public class ProductViewData
{
    public Product Product {get; set;}
    public bool CanEdit {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using [MvcContrib.FluentHtml](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) you can do like this (enhancing Todd Smith's suggestion):

```
<%=this.TextBox(x => x.Name).Size(50).Disabled(ViewData.Model.CanEdit)%>
```

Comment: Thanks... I guess I need to look into that. I marked Todd's reply as answer because I need to do that anyway, but your suggestion is good too.